# Where is the revoke.asc file once I've created it from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate, gnupg

Where is the `revoke.asc` file once I've created it from the command line? I've looked in the root of my home directory: `C:\Users\Me` and cannot find it. I've searched `*.asc` - no luck. If I run `gpg --armor --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke [your key ID]` a second time - it reports the `revoke.asc` file already exists, do I want to overwrite it? - so, it is there. Somewhere... but, where!? Here is what I see in the `cmd` prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub>gpg --armor --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke 7993DE75

sec  2048R/7993DE75 2015-12-31 John Doe (ABC123) <me@fake.net>

Create a revocation certificate for this key? (y/N) y
Please select the reason for the revocation:
  0 = No reason specified
  1 = Key has been compromised
  2 = Key is superseded
  3 = Key is no longer used
  Q = Cancel
(Probably you want to select 1 here)
Your decision? 0
Enter an optional description; end it with an empty line:
>
Reason for revocation: No reason specified
(No description given)
Is this okay? (y/N) y

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "John Doe (ABC123) <me@fake.net>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 7993DE75, created 2015-12-31

File `revoke.asc' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
Revocation certificate created.

Please move it to a medium which you can hide away; if Mallory gets
access to this certificate he can use it to make your key unusable.
It is smart to print this certificate and store it away, just in case
your media become unreadable.  But have some caution:  The print system of
your machine might store the data and make it available to others!

C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub>
```

I'm running Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Proper formatting goes a long way - there's a ? along with the other options that tells you what the markdown is

Comment: I would suspect it'd be in whatever directory your running the command from if you're not explicitly telling the --output switch to place it elsewhere. Otherwise, you might check the `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub` directory. If that doesn't turn up anything run the command with the output switch being explicit and then check for the file there i.e. `--output "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Revoke.asc"`

Comment: LMFAO  - thanks. I set an explicit output path to the desktop as you suggested - it worked. I still wonder where the default command left the file but, this works.

Answer (score 1):

When using `--output` without an absolute path, the path starts at the current working directory (like you did, just providing a file name), the file should have been stored in the working directory. Without `--output`, the revocation certificate would have been printed to the command line.

Now you're not supposed to write to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub` folder, and do not even have write privileges by default. Because of this (and keep compatibility to old versions of Windows, where this was allowed), the file access was redirected to an overlay directory in a hidden folder in your home directory `AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub`.

Go to some folder where you have write permissions, or provide the path to some folder where you're allowed to write.